# Vue.js: how to display the <br> element from the data property

Tags: vue.js

In my Vue.js project, I came into a problem as following

```
  data() {
    return {
      testData: 'aaaaaa<br>aaaaa',
    }
  }
```

and in the html template, I use it as  following:

```
<p>{{ testData }}</p>
```

but the `<br>` element doesn't work as expect, instead it display as string like `aaaaaa<br>aaaaa`

How to let the 
 element work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may need:

**template**

```
<p v-html="testData"></p>
```